# RouterLink with multiple params in Angular

Tags: angular, router, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-routerlink

I want to create a link to the route with multiple parameters and bind them in tempalte. Until now, I've been doing this by executing the function on `(click)` event, but I was wondering if it's possible within `RouterLink`'s binding.

Here is the function I use to bind parameters:

```
redirect() {
    this._router.navigate( ['/category', { cat: this.category, page: this.page }]);
}
```

My route looks like:

```
{
    path: 'category/:cat/:page',
    component: PostComponent
}
```

Will I be able to do the same inside `routerLink` directive?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes, of-course, you could use `routerLink` to form `href` tag dynamically for navigation. Values in array where each value will get evaluated against Component context.

```
[routerLink]="['/category', category, page ]"
```

Comment: Haha, I was actually thinking what I've done wrong until you edited. Thank you, it's working. I don't know why I couldn't find it in documentation. I was trying to do that same as you in the first answer and it created: href="/category;cat=1;page=1".

Comment: @DawidZbiński that was my bad. :D it will form `;` separated string which is wiered..

Comment: Nevermind, at the end everything works perfect. Thanks once again.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez glad to know it helps :)

Answer (score -5):

you can do it like, for example :-

```
<p *ngFor="let emp of employees; let i = index">
  <li><a [routerLink]="['delete', i]">{{emp.name}}</a>({{emp.status}})</li>
</p>
```

Hope it helps,

Thanks

Comment: I, unfortunately, think that this answer is not answering the question at all. There's no multiple params in router link you showed.

Comment: index i is dynamic for every employee which makes every delete url dynamic